# Unable to receive payment in USD using paypal button

Tags: paypal, paypal-buttons

I have created `Paypal` button using paypal selling tool, my business account is approved. If i try to pay in `INR`, my payment go through. But when i create button that receives payment in `USD`. The payment fails on the first page.

My `Paypal` Business account is registered in India. Error screenshot is as below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Currencies will be work correctly:** 
To resolve your issue, please kindly follow the below link to create an Indian Sandbox business account from the PayPal developer portal, set up your integration with that new Indian account and follow as mentioned below for currencies.
https://www.paypal.com/in/smarthelp/article/how-do-i-create-a-sandbox-test-account-ts1408

**USD for the Overseas customers**

> NOTE:
>   If an Overseas customer tries to make payment in the INR currency, it
>   gives an error on the PayPal checkout page. So, you've to use USD or
>   any other PayPal supported currency except INR for the overseas
>   customers.

**INR for the Indian Customers.**

> NOTE: 
>   If an Indian customer tries to make payment in a non-INR currency, it
>   gives an error on the PayPal checkout page. So, you've to use only INR
>   currency for the Indian customers.

For accepting payments in `INR` merchants have set primary currency is `INR` for the Overseas customers set  primary currency is `USD`

I hope this will work fine for cross-currency